# I'm looking for a way to assess network quality on a device before running a calabash script

Tags: android, adb, calabash, calabash-ios, calabash-android

Is this possible to do within calabash? I need to make this all automated and run a network assessment between scripts.

If this is not possible to do with calabash, is there a way do do it using adb on android?

edit: I don't want to embed this within the android/ios app I'm testing.

By network quality I mean internet access speed (time taken to download a file from a specific server).

Comment: what's "network quality"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up doing this using wget (installed using busy box).

I found a file of a set size on the internet (a 20MB zip from a speed checker site).
And I measured the time taken to download the file. Then did some simple maths to show the network speed in Kbs

```
b=`date +%s`
adb shell wget http://download.thinkbroadband.com/20MB.zip -P /data/local/tmp
a=`date +%s`
adb shell rm /data/local/tmp/20MB.zip
n=$(($a - $b))
d=$((160000/$n))
echo Network speed was measured at $d Kbs
```